# Linux connect from host to VirtualBox Guest over virtual serial port

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, serial-port

I need to retrieve config file from guest VM without network support. The simplest way to do that is probably to use serial port. As far as I understand I need to create kind of serial port "loop" so that I'll connect using eg. minicom to lets say /dev/vttyS0 and I'll assign /dev/vttyS1 to VirtualBox guest.

Guest is using baud rate 115200. How do I create such pair of devices?

I tried socat:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

However VirtualBox doesn't seem to understand it as correct serial device throwing error

```
Ioctl failed for serial host device /dev/pts/10 (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
Device will not work properly

ErrorID DrvHostSerialFail
Severity Warning
```

Comment: Installing Guest additions, so you can mount a shared storage into both Guest and Host, is out of the question?

Comment: @MarekRost it's proprietary embedded OS. Doesn't have standard prompt nor even direct access to drive. It only has configuration prompt with command that dumps device configuration to console output. It seems to be the only way to get config out of device. It doesn't even support framebuffer, VirtualBox is displaying standard VM monitor using serial port 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First Setup Serial Console Setting in Host OS.** 

In virtualbox setting, 

serial Ports --> Port 1

Port No. COM1

Port Mode - Host Pipe

connect to existing pipe/socked - UNCHECKED

Path/Addess: /tmp/vbox

**Now, Set Minicom**

sudo  minicom -s -c on

 Serial port setup 

 Serial Device : unix#/tmp/vbox 

 Exit

**Enable Serial Console In Guest** 

 sudo vi /etc/default/grub 

 **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0 ignore_loglevel"** 

 sudo update-grub 

 **Now Enable getty On Console ttyS0** 

 **For Upstart Sytem** 

 1) Create a file called /etc/init/ttyS0.conf containing the following:

```
# ttyS0 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on ttyS0 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[12345]
stop on runlevel [!12345]
```

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyS0 vt102

2) Ask upstart to start the getty

```
sudo start ttyS0
```

**For Systemd Systems**

```
# sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
# sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now reboot your guest os and you will get serial console on your host os via minicom

Comment: for RHEL base system use: `grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink -e /etc/grub2.conf)"`

Answer (score 1):

The way to connect from host to guest is to

1. Create serial port in virtualbox in "Host Pipe" mode with path eg. /dev/vboxttyS0.
2. **enable that serial port in guest**
3. Use `socat unix-connect:/dev/vboxttyS0 -,b57600` or `socat unix-connect:/dev/vboxttyS0 -,raw,echo=0` which in my particular case worked better.

I contacted OS vendor and it turns out serial ports have to be enabled explicitly, even though on bare metal devices they're enabled by default :/